# Coalesce of multiple values group by date in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table as shown below:

[image: [actual]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/267Ew.png]

I need to select columns based on identity_no and also, need to select non zero/non null column values grouped by src_date. so when I query on the identity_no, I want something like: 
[image: result]

I need a postgresql statement or even a function is ok. I tried with coalesce. but i can't do group by on src_date. Here src_date is a string and not a date

Comment: What if there are different non-empty `email` or `download` for a `src_date`?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe any one value is ok. In one more similar table, it has a column with timestamp. so in such cases may be latest one would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `group by` and `max()`

```
select scr_date,max(upload) as upload, max(download) as download, identity_no, max(email) as email,
max(phone) as phone, min(id) as id
from tablename
group by scr_date,identity_no
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to group your table by `scr_date` and other columns need to be aggregated with a method such as `min` or `max`. From your output, it seems that the `id` is the minimum of each group. Other columns don't containt multiple values for each group, therefore `min` and `max` would work the same. However you should consider if other columns had multiple values for each group, how would you want them to be aggregated.

```
select min(id) as id, max(upload) as upload, max(download) as download, max(email) as email, max(phone) as phone, scr_date
from tbl
group by scr_date
```

Comment: In case the table had a column called timestamp and had the date and time of creation, can we select the latest value for the src_date?

Comment: Yes, then you need to group your table by `timestamp` and call the `max` function on `src_data`.